# how to shrink a file to some parts and parallel copy them

Tags: c#, file-copying

I have a big file that should be copied. Here are my codes:

```
const int CopyBufferSize = 64 * 1024;
//about 4 GB
string src = @"F:\Test\src\Setup.exe";
string dst = @"F:\Test\dst\Setup.exe";

    private void btnCopySection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(CopySection);
        t.Start();
    }

    public void CopySection()
    {
        Stream input = File.OpenRead(src);
        long length = input.Length;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[CopyBufferSize];
        Stopwatch swTotal = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            progressBar1.Maximum = (int)Math.Abs(length / CopyBufferSize) + 1;
        });


        using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(dst))
        {
            int bytesRead = 1;
            // This will finish silently if we couldn't read "length" bytes.
            // An alternative would be to throw an exception
            while (length > 0 && bytesRead > 0)
            {
                bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(CopyBufferSize, buffer.Length));
                output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                length -= bytesRead;

                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    progressBar1.Value++;
                    label1.Text = (100 * progressBar1.Value / progressBar1.Maximum).ToString() + " %";
                    label3.Text = ((int)swTotal.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString() + " Seconds";
                });
            }

            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Maximum;
            });
        }

        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            swTotal.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Total time: {0:N4} seconds.", swTotal.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            label3.Text += ((int)swTotal.Elapsed.TotalSeconds - int.Parse(label3.Text.Replace(" Seconds",""))).ToString() + " Seconds";
        });
    }
```

Actually I am shrinking the file in 64 KB parts and copy them one by one(64 KB is the optimal copy-buffer-size).

I know moving a file is much more quick than copying it(in same drive). If we could modify these codes and copy the parts separately and then move parts together we can optimize copy speed.

I know two processes can't do on same file. I can handle it by reading the file into a buffer but when I am creating the total file I don't know what to do.

Is it possible to use `Stream.Seek` method in order to shrink the file and then write these parts separately and then stick them together? Any idea?

Comment: `If we could modify these codes and copy the parts separately and then move parts together we can optimize copy speed` this doesn't make any sense

Comment: You can probably do something the equivalent of split a file into 64k chunks and send parallel parts, to be saved by the client as chunks and then do the equivalent of merge them together. However, Id expect the download speed of n chunks to take the same as the overall download of one large unless you have throttled connections. Plus it would have overhead of putting it back together.

Comment: I want to do something like download managers @GeraldSchneider. I am trying to describe my theory and use your help.

Comment: @BugFinder 1 up vote for helping me to describe the issue. 

I want to use threads in order to construct the file like workers. Each thread will make it's own part. I want some helping codes please.

Comment: Well @MostafaKhodakarami we dont tend to write your code for you - more, try find why your code doesnt do what you thought or expected. If you were to be ftp'ing data, ftp servers often allow broken downloads to be resumed, so can effectively be downloaded in parts because you can get file.part1 as 0-640000 bytes, and then 640001-1280000 as the next.. You've decided 64k is the optimal size, but, surely thats dependant on where you're copying to/from however, you would need to write your own file sender and receiver, show us what you've got, how far you've got, what is stopping you eg - the bug

Comment: The code in the OP copies a file from one destination to another on the same disk. Doing this in multiple threads will rather make the copy process slower than faster, because the head of the hard disk will have to constantly move between different positions (at least on a non-SSD disk, with large files).

Comment: @GeraldSchneider an up vote for you. You are right in HDD and I am using HDD. So it can't be happen?

Comment: It's not that it can't happen, it's just that it's going to make everything slower. Download managers are designed to overcome (forced) throttling limitations, there's no such thing in what you're doing. You're taking a cheat in one system to an environment where the limit doesn't exist - there's nothing to cheat. There's no benefit from doing what you're trying to do - in part exactly because of the caching I mentioned in my answer to your other question.

Comment: You are right @Luaan. I had a look on task manager and I saw my disk is doing what it can but it was not enough for me. I understand the limitation source now. Thank you all.